# Attribute's type change with inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class A, working on a specific kind of objects (instances of A there). I'd like to have a class B, which has mostly (i.e. not all its methods are the same) the same behavior, but which is working on a different class of objects (B there).

Here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void perform() { data.push_back(A()); };
    std::vector<A> data;
};


class B : protected A
{
public:
    B() : A() {}
    void test() { perform(); }
    std::vector<B> data;
};


int main()
{
    B b;
    b.test();
    std::cout << b.data.size() << std::endl;
}


// output: 0
// I expected: 1
```

I was expecting `std::vector<B>` to be used during the insertion instead of `std::vector<A>`, as B is a subclass of B.

What am I missing? Is there a way I can make sure every method defined in class A work as expected in class B?

Thanks!

Comment: Make A a class template if you really need to push-back actual B's in there.

Comment: I was thinking of templating the class, it felt like it was mostly like performing inheritance's job by hand.

Also, what if I want to instantiate any of A or B? Like that:

`A* var = new A();` or `A* var = new B()`?

Comment: My bad, that code should be better.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance-based polymorphism in C++ only deals with *functions*, not *data elements*. That is, changing the object's type only affects which function is called, not which data element is used.

Also, you cannot assign an object of type `A` to a container of `B`'s. Ignoring polymorphism, you can't do:

```
std::vector<B> data;
data.push_back(A());
```

That's because `B` inherits from `A`, not the other way around.

Third, the assignment would have to use *pointers* anyway, not outright objects. So you'd have to do something like:

```
std::vector<A*> data;
data.push_back(new B);
```

Comment: OK I see. So my only solution is the one given by dario_ramos, which is templating my class?

Comment: @Thomas I haven't the slightest clue what you're actually trying to solve, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

When you need the same behavior for different types, use a template:

```
template <typename Element>
class Container
{
public:
    void perform() { data.push_back(Element()); };
    std::vector<Element> data;
};

int main(){
    Container<A> a;
    Container<B> b;
    a.perform();
    b.perform();
    std::cout << a.data.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << b.data.size() << std::endl;
}
```

**Disclaimer**: not compile tested